# How do you restart the MSP430 Launchpad programmatically with Energia?

Tags: msp430, reset, launchpad, energia

Can anybody tell me what Energia method I can call to programatically reset the MSP430 Launchpad.  Under certain circumstances, I need it to power down and back up again.  It needs to shut down power to its I2C devices when it resets itself.

Comment: Which LaunchPad? And I don't know of any LaunchPad that has I²C devices; have you connected external devices?

Comment: Yes they are external

Comment: **Which LaunchPad?** And show the schematic of your circuit.

Comment: MSP-EXP430G2 LaunchPad  Assume it is stand alone.  I just want to programmatically reset/reboot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a BOR or POR directly in code for Valueline MSP430G2xxx. You can do a partial reset PUC though.

You can do three things for a reset:

- **Full reset by pulling the RST pin low. You have to use a spare GPIO pin, and set it to output low. Produces a full Power-On Reset (POR).**
- Password Violation Reset. Write to the Watchdog timer control register without the valid password. i.e. `WDTCTL = 0;`. Also write to flash without the password, or read/jump to an invalid address. Easiest with the WDTCTL. This is a Power-Up Clear (PUC), not a full reset.
- Enable the Watchdog mode of the Watchdog Timer, and let it time out. This is a WDTTO, also a PUC.

See section 2.1 of the [MSP430G2xx family guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf) for full details.